# I have error "local.ERROR: Class "App\Http\Controllers\Category" does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1):

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am new to laravel and I am sorry that my English is so bad.

I create app that has many-to-many relations with laravel + vue.

The relationship between models is recipe and category.

I am trying to store a recipe related to the category.

but when submitting recipe data with form tag, error occure.

The error is below.

> local.ERROR: Class "App\Http\Controllers\Category" does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class "App\Http\Controllers\Category" does not exist at /home/sakamotosora/Desktop/recipehouse-laravue/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php:81)
> [stacktrace]

The code I wrote looks like this.

```
// RecipeController.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Recipe;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class RecipeController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Category $category, Reqeust $request)
    {
        logger()->error();
        $recipe = new Recipe();

        $recipe->title = $request->title;

        $recipe->save();

        return redirect()
            ->route('category.show', $category);
        // return back();
    }
}
```

```
// CategoryShowCOmponent.vue
<script setup>


const props = defineProps({
  categoryId: String,
})

const newRecipe = ref('')

let categoryId = parseInt(route.params.categoryId)

const addRecipe = () => {
    recipes.value.push(newRecipe.value)
    submitNewRecipe()
    newRecipe.value = ''
}

const submitNewRecipe = () => {
    axios.post('/api/categories/' + categoryId + '/recipes/store', {
        title: newRecipe.value
    })
}

</script>

<template>

        <form method="post" v-on:submit.prevent="addRecipe">
            <input type="text" v-model="newRecipe">
        </form>

</template>
```

Since the amount of code is large, irrelevant code is omitted.

```
// api.php
Route::post('/categories/{category}/recipes/store', [RecipeController::class, 'store']);
```

I checked for typo for example, Recipecontroller (c is lower case)

thankyou for your help!

Comment: It seems like you haven't imported the Category Model into the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `use App\Models\Category;` on top of controller.

Update, Next there is a type on `Request` as well, you need to update to:

```
 public function store(Request $request, Category $category)
```

you are using `Reqeust` instead.

Also, I am not sure, if there will $category on store case, because the model might only be supplied while updating.

Comment: I made an honest mistake.
I should have checked many times, but I couldn't

Comment: I added App\Models\Category, but another error occurred.

local.ERROR: Class "App\Http\Controllers\Reqeust" does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class \"App\\Http\\Controllers\\Reqeust\" does not exist at /home/sakamotosora/Desktop/recipehouse-laravue/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php:81)
[stacktrace]

Comment: I added use App\Http\Controllers\Request;
but error says  "Cannot use App\\Http\\Controllers\\Request as Request because the name is already in use",

I followed the instructions in the error but it didn't work.

What do you know about this?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I already wrote store(Request $reqest).
Are you pointing to another Request $request?

Comment: no its same, is your issue solved now?

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I didn't understand your English meaning, sorry.